# c++ dll runtime error floating point support not loaded

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

Calling out to all the proffesional developers out there... I am breaking my head for 2 days now trying to find out this issue...

I am attaching a custom dll to a executable, and in that dll all I use is detours.
I installed and tried to recompile with VS2008, VS2010, VS2013, I also tried different settings, I also reinstalled and checked all the vs++ distros, nothing seems to fix it. I can't even do a proper debug on it, as I don't have the .exe pdb. I am willing to post the code I am using, but it`s on google, so nothing special..

Procedure I did: Hook the dll, and detour send() and recv().
Please help me fix this, or tell me how could I debug it, as I am at the end of the line...

Error:
**MICROSOFT VISUAL C++ Runtime Library R6002 floating point not loaded.**

Comment: Check for c-style IO calls that specify a floating point format without providing a float. Eg: `int val; printf("%f", val);`

Comment: Well Thanks, I will check... but all I am doing is detour so there is nothing like printf...

Comment: The next suggestion is to narrow down the problem with the Visual Studio debugger. Run the program and wait for it to crash. Inspect the stack trace (defaults to the bottom right pane in debug mode, I think), looking for unusual values in the variables. Also keep an eye out for functions with a variable arguments list because that can trigger the same problem as `printf`.

Comment: Thanks I tried to debug, but the .exe does not allow me to... anyway, you think printf could be the issue ?

Comment: Rebuild the exe in release mode?

Comment: Ran across this with visual studio 2010 a few years back porting some C code. Lemme see if I can find the page.

Comment: But I wrote in my post, I don`t have the .exe source... I am just attaching a dll. Anyway, is there another way I could hook the send() and recv() without using detours ?

Comment: To be honest I don't know what detours is, but if the exe was built against a particular version of it and you can't rebuild the exe, I'd find and use that version. Here's the page I was talking about. My answer was the printf. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1x26e0x(v=vs.100).aspx. Yours might just be a library mismatch.

Comment: Thank you... I`m not giving up, there must be a solution.

Comment: That error is similar to what the old Borland compilers would give if none of your code actually uses `double` or `float`.  The solution was to make a call to some function like `sqrt`, i.e. a function that actually takes / returns a double, not one that *allows* doubles, like `printf`.

Comment: LOL.... I just found the only piece of code wich could cause this... "for(int i = 0 ; i != Len ; ++i)" is this the problem ?

Comment: I think I remember why the Borland compiler gave this (almost exact) error.  You're calling a function that can implicitly take floating point arguments, but the linker cannot detect that you used a floating point "trigger", like a printf() format string that implies that floating point is used, therefore the linker will not bring in the floating point library.  This was intended (I guess) to be a program size optimization strategy at the time.  I don't know if this is the same reasoning as the VS compiler, but just giving you what I remember w.r.t to Borland and this very same error.

Comment: Ok thanks @PaulMcKenzie, any suggestions on what should I do ? some example maybe ?

Comment: What @PaulMcKenzie remembers lines up exactly with what I ran into with `printf` and is documented in the MSDN link I posted earlier. In my case I solved the problem by replacing `printf` with `cout` Paul's suggestion of putting in a mindless call to `sqrt` or similar somewhere in your code where it will have no performance impact and won't be compiled out should at least confirm the theory. As for `for(int i = 0 ; i != Len ; ++i)` being a problem, Not enough context. If Len is floating point you're going to have to add an epsilon to compare it with int, but shouldn't cause what you've seen.