# Issue running program in DOS 5.02

Tags: qbasic

We are trying to run certain .exe programs on a IBM 486 running DOS 5.02 to make sure
they are backwards compatible. When attempting to compile an QBasic 4.5 program with BC.EXE
we get the following error and would like to know how to solve it.:

```
runtime error R6002
- floating point not loaded.
```

Comment: The comments to this answer explain how to fix for Borland, despite the title being about Visual C. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35871034/c-dll-runtime-error-floating-point-support-not-loaded

Comment: You mean QuickBASIC and not QBasic. QBasic can not compile programs.

Comment: I get them confused. I am using QB45.

Answer (score 0):

That means your program (or runtime) was compiled to run with math coprocessor only and machine does not have 80x87 math coprocessor.

Comment: No, it means that floating support was not linked. It is a build configuration issue, not a runtime issue.

Comment: Since it an error with the missing fpu we are going to scrap it.